# How can I use Jupyter to run a web server and process web forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cloud-hosting

I'm quite experienced using Jupyter and running Python scripts with it. But I'm trying to figure out how to host Jupyter on a Cloud host for instance Digital Ocean and use it as an engine to analyse inputs and data on the web.
Let me explain better; Assuming I want a public user to input a sample data.
On the webpage, a typical users sees a blank form field to input his name. At the back end, Jupyter accepts the inputted string, runs and output the result back to the webpage.
Typically on Jupyter, I would run the code below:

```
x = input("What is your surname")
if x[0] > G:
    print(" Please proceed to Section C")
```

This is what is expected to happen on the web, [User webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvy3L.png) as you can see the user does not see Jupyter.

[image]

If anyone has a guide or maybe pointing to a detailed tutorial or link will also be of good help too.

Comment: What can Jupyter do that plain Python can't do? Look up some Python web frameworks like Django or Flask.

Comment: I agree with you, however there is no harm in exploring the possibilities. Quite a lot of Data Scientists use Jupyter and in some cases exclusively. It would be nice to open up the possibility of interacting with the public on Data Science issues and outputting answers instantaneously.

Comment: Fair enough. You could install Django or Flask alongside Jupyter. Then you would be able to run them from Jupyter.

Comment: Is your question "How can I install Jupyter on a cloud host?" or is it "How can I use Jupyter to run a web server and process web forms?"

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila). It runs any IPython notebook as a Tornado web app. Many examples are provided in the repo and in [Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/).